# C Programming - Sprintf & String Arrays

Tags: c, string

I've been reading a few other questions from folks on arrays of strings.  I drew some insight and changed my code, but one problem I'm having is incorporating sprintf.

High level, the purpose of this will ultimately be a function to fopen/fread a variable number of files in a directory. But getting hung up on this string manipulation portion.

I'd like to increment my pointers within sprintf, but I'm getting segmentation issues.  Any thoughts on fixing what I have or perhaps a different route? MAX = 20, FILES = 4.

```
char fName_A[MAX];
char fName_B[MAX];
char * ptr_A[FILES];
char * ptr_B[FILES];
int i;

for(i=0; i<FILES; i++){
    sprintf(fName_A, "waveA00%d.bin", i);
    sprintf(fName_B, "waveB00%d.bin", i);

    ptr_A[i] = fName_A;
    ptr_B[i] = fName_B;

    printf("Ch1 File Number %d is named %s\n", i, *(ptr_A+i));
    printf("Ch2 File Number %d is named %s\n", i, *(ptr_B+i));
}

printf("fName_A[0] = %s\n", *ptr_A);
printf("fName_A[1] = %s\n", *(ptr_A + 1));
printf("fName_A[2] = %s\n", *(ptr_A + 2));
printf("fName_A[3] = %s\n", *(ptr_A + 3));

return 0;
```

Comment: *Debug this* and you'll find every pointer in `ptr_A` points to the same buffer `fName_A`, and likewise with the `B` side with its pointers and buffer. That means the *last* filename you wrote for each will be replicate across the pointer array, because they're all the same address.

Comment: Forgot to include my results, basically my pointers take on only the last loop item, which is what I was testing w/ all of the printf statements after.  I figured this would happen, but I was having segmentation faults passing the pointers themselves.

Comment: @WhozCraig exactly

Comment: [No warnings or faults with this code.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2998fce911ee23bc) Valgrind will report no invalid reads or writes. Whatever segfault you're having, it isn't here. The logic is busted, as covered earlier, and maybe whatever you're doing with those arrays in code not here is breaking. *Use your debugger* and catch the fault in action; it should help lead you to where the wheels fell off.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using eg. `*(ptr_A+i)` instead of just `ptr_A[i]`? (it works just as well -- it's just odd)

Comment: @WhozCraig hmm, alright, I was compiling and running just in Mac Terminal with gcc, but I'll try your suggestion on debugging.

Comment: @Dmitri no real reasons, definitely understand that I could also just use ptr_A[i]

Comment: This is what I was trying and getting segmentation faults  `for(i=0; i<FILES; i++){
        sprintf(ptr_A[i], "waveA00%d.bin", i);
        sprintf(ptr_B[i], "waveB00%d.bin", i);`

Comment: The problem with the `sprintf(ptr_A[i]...` version is probably that `ptr_A[i]` etc. have not been set to valid pointers first... allocate some space for the strings and set the pointers in `ptr_A` and `ptr_B` first, and it'd work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allocating any memory for strings associated with Ptr_A and Ptr_B, just setting the pointers to point to the buffers fName_A and fName_B, so when you check at the end, they all point to the last string stored in these buffers.

Fix it by allocating store for each filename in A and B as an array of chars, instead of using pointers. Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX   100
#define FILES 4

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 char fName_A[MAX];
 char fName_B[MAX];
 char A[FILES][MAX];
 char B[FILES][MAX];
 int i;

 for(i=0; i<FILES; i++){
    sprintf(fName_A, "waveA00%d.bin", i);
    sprintf(fName_B, "waveB00%d.bin", i);

    strcpy(A[i], fName_A);
    strcpy(B[i], fName_B);

    printf("Ch1 File Number %d is named %s\n", i, A[i]);
    printf("Ch2 File Number %d is named %s\n", i, B[i]);
 }

 for(i=0; i<FILES; i++) {
    printf("A[%d] = %s\n", i, A[i]);
    printf("B[%d] = %s\n", i, B[i]);
 }
}
```

This will output the following:

```
Ch1 File Number 0 is named waveA000.bin
Ch2 File Number 0 is named waveB000.bin
Ch1 File Number 1 is named waveA001.bin
Ch2 File Number 1 is named waveB001.bin
Ch1 File Number 2 is named waveA002.bin
Ch2 File Number 2 is named waveB002.bin
Ch1 File Number 3 is named waveA003.bin
Ch2 File Number 3 is named waveB003.bin
A[0] = waveA000.bin
B[0] = waveB000.bin
A[1] = waveA001.bin
B[1] = waveB001.bin
A[2] = waveA002.bin
B[2] = waveB002.bin
A[3] = waveA003.bin
B[3] = waveB003.bin
```

Comment: Ah very interesting!  Appreciate the solution and explanation for my problem ScottK!